# MKMapView change colors

Tags: mkmapview

Anyone know of a way to change the colors of a MKMapView?  Is there a way to XOR an image over or blend one that you could "possibly" create a "night version" of the map that isn't so bright?

Thanks!

Dan

Answer (score 1):

better solution would be to add custom colored overlays

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a UIView with a 50% alpha that covered the MKMapView, but then you will have UI problems. I am assuming the [Satellite](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKMapType) mode doesn't suit?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is adding a MKAnnotation with a 50% transparent black background color. Then I moved the annotation to the back of the stack maintained by the mapview, so that all the other annotations can still be interacted with.

Where it really gets interesting is when the map moves... OK if you are on iOS4 but a little tricky on iOS3 devices. Well, I figured it out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @RolandasR, you can try creating a custom overlay as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592117/3847