# Change map colors in iOS MapView?

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is it possible to change map element colors in a MapView in the same way that you can with a Google Map?  If so, how would I go about doing this.

I'm looking to change map element colors pretty substantially, so I don't think that adding an Annotation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441230/mkmapview-change-colors) is the right solution.

As an example, http://geo.rkn.la has a map that is skinned to be grayscale, and Google has documentation of how to do this for web maps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave CloudMade a try, and it wound up working reasonably well, but I decided against using them for two reasons:

1) Their support sucks.  I shot an email to their support address about a week or two ago and have still not received any kind of response.  Their most recent SVN commit is also close to a year old.

2) [This issue](https://github.com/route-me/route-me/issues/170) raised on the Route Me repo, combined with their shoddy support, scared me away.

I did manage to find an SDK called [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/) that is also built on Route Me that was suitable for the task.  Their git repo is in active development and they are available on freenode during normal business hours.  I'd recommend them over CloudMade to anyone who has the same question I had initially.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using UIMapKit.

I have used [CloudMade](https://web.archive.org/web/20120915063837/http://cloudmade.com/products/iphone-sdk) before, which enable you to customise map colours quite extensively. As far as I know their maps use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data.

Comment: I'm not sure if CloudMade is as cost effective as using UIMapKit, but someone else pointed me at [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/), which is an Open Source solution they provide.

Using that inside of a UIWebView seems like a potentially reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with the current MapKit.

Any substantial update like the one you describe would have to be performed when requesting tiles from Google, and at the moment only Apple does this, deep in the framework.