# Changing Color/Alpha/Filter to MKMapView iOS 6

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, mkmapview

Is there a way to apply CI Filters to `MKMapViews`? Or something similar? I'm trying to not have my map based app looks so beige. Is there way to apply `RGBA` filters?

Any help/tutorials direction appreciated. I see nothing in the native documentation that talks about changing look for `MKMapView`.

Comment: I think the only supported way to style MKMapView is through the mapType.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no practical way to change the appearance of MKMapViews. You might want to checkout some of the more customizable alternatives such as https://github.com/route-me/route-me.

Comment: Can you please assist how you got solution working ? I tried creating demo but it just crashes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you can change the imagery before it is rendered to the screen.  However, you can use an MKOverlayView over the entire world that achieves the same effect.  The following should work, but treat it like pseudocode just to get you started.

```
@interface MapTileOverlay : NSObject <MKOverlay>
@end

@implementation MapTileOverlay
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        boundingMapRect = MKMapRectWorld;
        coordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake(boundingMapRect.origin.x + boundingMapRect.size.width/2, boundingMapRect.origin.y + boundingMapRect.size.height/2));
    }
    return self;
}
@end


@interface MapTileOverlayView : MKOverlayView
@end

@implementation MapTileOverlayView
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);  //check docs for other blend modes
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);  //use whatever color to mute the beige
    CGContextFillRect(context, [self rectForMapRect:mapRect]);
}
@end
```

You need to have some class that implements the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol to create the view...

```
@interface MapViewDelegate : NSObject<MKMapViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation MapViewDelegate
-(MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MapTileOverlay class]]) {
        return [[MapTileOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Finally, after you initialize your map, you need to set the delegate on the map and add the overlay...you must set the delegate before you add the overlay...

```
MapViewDelegate* delegate = [[MapViewDelegate alloc] init];  //you need to make this an iVar somewhere
[map setDelegate:delegate];
[map addOverlay:[[MapTileOverlay alloc] init]];
```

Comment: Would I init this on my mapView's viewForOverlay? A little more guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Great work, this appears to add an overlay to the whole map. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this using your approach and the overlay works well but the blend mode does not seem to be applied. Any ideas why?

Comment: boundingMapRect where to declare this ? Can you please assist ?

Comment: @JanakNirmal The class extends the MKOverlay delegate, which requires you to synthesize those two properties - once you do that you should be able to access in the initializer

Comment: This approach works but when moving the map, it does paint the entire map. Am I right @Eric ?  Does anyone know about other solution?

Comment: In the above example, the `boundingMapRect` is for the whole world.  If you don't want the whole world, change that variable to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a view on top of the map view,
nearly transparent with a slight color (e.g blueish to compensate that brown.)